# anchor tag not being rendered as a link in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

Hi am trying to replace a text url in my text editor to an active link.I am using a WYSIWYG text-editor. Here is my jquery code :

```
  var urlRegex = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/;
  $("#queEditor").text().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
  return '<a href="' + url + '">' + data + '</a>';
```

But this is just changing the text url in the editor to actual text anchor tag for ex. if i put the text as `http://www.mangareader.net/93-44-12/naruto/chapter-39.html` then the output is `<a href="http://www.mangareader.net/93-44-12/naruto/chapter-39.html">Naruto 39 - Read Naruto 39 Online - Page 12</a>`.
I want the output to be an active link not just text in my text-editor. How can i rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Do check your var UrlRegex, the http stuff before semicolon I guess should be in inverted commas.

like:

```
 var urlRegex = "/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/";
```

Please reply if it worked for you:
Do the following for anchoring a text.

1) Type the text that will serve as the link.

2) Highlight that text and click the Link button as seen below in the WYSYWIG Editor. If you are using the HTML Editor, click on the Link button that appears.

3) Enter the target URL of the link. This should be the name of the anchor you entered previously prefaced with a # character. Click OK.